# How to increment BigInteger value using MongoTemplate?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

```
public void updateWalletBalance(final String walletId, final BigInteger amount){    
var query = query(where("wallets.walletId").is(walletId));
    var update = new Update().inc("wallets.$.balance", amount);
    mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Client.class);
}
```

I get this exception > 'org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException' exception.. "Cannot increment with non-numeric argument: {wallets.$.balance: "100000"}"

Comment: what is the datatype in your MongoDB for balance?

Comment: The Wallet document (Java Class) has a balance field with BigInteger datatype. While saving it into the collection with MongoRepository, it is storing this field as string type.

Comment: @user2201232  here are list of allowed datatypes https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/. I suggest you use the long datatype for the amount if it is a very large value. I suspect your BigInteger datatype is converted to a string internally when you run it.